# Is running an add on like "No Script" in Firefox needed on a Linux system?

Tags: firefox, security, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use No-Script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33499/should-i-use-no-script)

A friend recommended the "No Script" add on for Firefox, however this friend runs a Windows system. Is running "No Script" on a Linux system really needed? I'm running Firefox 9 on an Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit system. I try to use repository programs only, and am utilizing the firewall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I see it. When I used to run "No Script" it wasn't so much because I was worried about viruses or malware, but because I didn't want advertising companies tracking what I was doing. So while No Script on a Windows system is good for virus prevention, and a few other things. Running No Script on and Unix based system will still protect you - for the most part - from wandering eyes tracking your online activities.

So in short if you were wanting to run No Script to protect you from viruses, then no its not really necessary. But if you wanting to run it for pretty much any of its other uses, then yah you can go ahead and run it. Hope I was of some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about security, I'd recommend using the [MVPS](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm) hosts file to block advertizing and malaware. To get it, you can download and extract it, then copy its contents to your hosts file, save and close it. Effects kick in immediately, works with every browser as well. Here are the commands:

```
wget http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.zip
unzip ./hosts.zip
gedit ./HOSTS
```

Then copy the whole content and close it.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/hosts
```

Paste at the bottom, save and close. That should block pretty much anything you had NoScript blocking for you. Feel free to use NoScript if you don't like Flash and JavaScript loading by default, but otherwise there's not much of a need for it in Linux.